# Brightness control in Windows 7 Home Basic

Tags: brightness

I re-installed Windows 7 Home Basic to my laptop, now the brightness is not adjusting but before installing it was changing.

No option to change brightness in display setting was shown, how can I change it again?

Comment: Have you installed all OEM drivers?

Answer (score 1):

To control the brightness from your keyboard shortcuts you need specific drivers for your laptop model. You also need the video/graphics card drivers for your laptop.
After those 2 steps you will be able to control the brightness levels in the control panel and  as normal.
Like Ramhound asked if you installed all OEM drivers, this makes sure your laptop will run like before.